# Bash function variable command not found error

Tags: bash, function

I have a bash script like this with a function

```
_launch()
{
  ${1}
}

testx()
{
  _launch "TESTX=1 ls -la"
}

testx
```

I get error "TESTX=1 command not found" in _launch function. Why?
When I run `TESTX=1 ls -la` directly on shell it works fine.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why can't you pass the value of `TESTX` as a separate argument?

Comment: I want to launch an app with variable value set. ls -la is just an example

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to use variables to hold commands.  See [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

As long as you are dealing with executables and not shell built-ins, you could do this:

```
_launch() {
    env $1
}
```

This won't play well in case you have literal spaces in values used in `var=value` pairs or arguments to the command being launched.

You can overcome this problem by just passing the command to the launch function and setting your variables in function invocation itself, like this:

```
_launch() {
    #       your launch prep steps here...
    "$@"  # run the command
    #       post launch code here
}
TESTX=1 TESTY=2 TESTZ=3 _launch ls -la
```

The variables would be passed down to the launched command as environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because first looks at the statement to see whether we have a variable assignment, and then does parameter expansion. In your case, bash doesn't recognize that you want to extend the environment for your ls command, and treats TESTX=1 as command to be executed.

For the same reason, the following does **not** set the bash variable ABC:

```
x='ABC=55'
$x
```

This would print *ABC=55: command not found*.